# Стоит ли удалять вопросы, нарушающие пользовательские соглашения сторонних сервисов?

Tags: обсуждение, правила

Вот пример, натолкнувший меня на эту мысль: [Парсинг телефона с мобильной версии авито](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541880/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be) Были и другие примеры, но их уже не найти.

И [соглашение](https://www.avito.ru/info/polzovatelskoe_soglashenie) - обратите внимание на пункт 5.3. Естественно, законность всего этого определяется юристами, но будь я владельцем похожего сервиса, мне было бы неприятно, когда спамеры используют его в своих гадких целях. Нельзя утверждать, что пользователь, задавший вопрос использует номер телефона для чего-то незаконного или просто некрасивого (может напарсит телефонов и захочет продать базу?), но нельзя же в самом деле оставлять готовые рецепты на всеобщее обозрение? Вообще, можно применять правило - сервис не предоставляет публичного API - значит парсинг странички роботом запрещен соглашением.

Comment: так ведь подобный вопрос можно и *завуалировать*, и что тогда как быть в таком случае?! простой пример: у меня есть json/xml/html как мне оттуда достать {то что необходимо достать}

Comment: @Bald, с хитро придуманными вопросами ничего не поделаешь, но часто никто ничего не прячет.

Comment: похожий вопрос обсуждали не так давно: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/

Comment: Несмотря на положительный отзыв о таких пограничных вопросах в упомянутом опросе, фактически вопросы об обходе API/ограничений часто минусуются и закрываются.

Comment: @VladD, пока я не написал этот вопрос, вопрос про телефоны, как и ответ был заплюсован. Вот кому понадобиться чужие актуальные номера телефонов массово получать? Суд линча может и решит как поступить, заминусовав, но многие аналогичные вопросы могут быть пропущены. Будут ли модераторы реагировать на тревогу с вышеописанной причиной?

Comment: @m9_psy, не будут. Есть консенсус, что каждый сам решает, портить ли себе карму, отвечая на подобные вопросы или проходить мимо, минусуя.

Comment: "*Вообще, можно применять правило - сервис не предоставляет публичного API - значит парсинг странички роботом запрещен соглашением*" - нельзя.